# Update application SQLite database created by Assets DB

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, sqlite

I have Database in my application which is created by just coping the SQLite database file from the assets folder but now in the next release I want to update the database without losing the previous data.

Is there any Logic or way to copy the previous data and create a new database through SQLiteOpenHelper so that in near future I will not face this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Use this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kdehairy/4372554)
2. In the `OnUpgrade` method, copy your previous data from the old database.
3. In the `doUpgrade` method, use your copied data to update the new database.

Comment: But here it will copy the database only from the Assets and If I used this my db will be on its initial stage. I want to preserve the data also in newly copied database.

Comment: 1. old_db is in user.
2. in your upgraded version, ship the new_db in the assets folder.
3. the user upgrades his old version.
4. the new version starts.
5. in OnUpgrade method, read your previous data from old_db.
6. in doUpgrade method, write your previous data to new_db.
So, at the end, it's your new_db that is in use but loaded with the data from the old_db

Answer (score 0):

Previous data will be kept by default when users update to a new version. but you must keep in mind there will be new users never get a former version app. So you should add complete database in the assets folder.